# extern vars and struct defined in other source file

Tags: c, struct, typedef, extern

Have two files with struct definitions. Header:

```
typedef struct _InputData InputData;
extern InputData input_data;
```

and source file:

```
struct _InputData{
    char const*modification_l;
    char const*amount_l;
    char const*units_l;
};
InputData input_data = {...};
```

When i try to use input_data from other source file it gives me "invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘InputData’". I think i understand why it happened, but how i can deal with it in the gracefullest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have do define the complete structure in the header file. Otherwise there is no way to know what fields it have, i.e. it's incomplete.

Comment: Or better, define it only in the header and then include the header in the source file.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Ah, thats what I was meant... Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this approach (more or less), but you need to define the struct as a pointer instead:

header

```
extern struct InputData* input_data;
```

source file:

```
struct InputData{
    char const*modification_l;
    char const*amount_l;
    char const*units_l;
};

InputData* input_data; 
...
input_data = malloc(sizeof(InputData));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to a `struct` defined elsewhere, but not an instance. Compiler doesn't know what is the structure and how to calculate memory offsets for such a variable.

Why do you put the `struct` definition in the C file? put it in the header.

Comment: i tried but it said "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Comment: @Yola, yes, if the struct definition is still not known when you dereference - the compiler would still not know how to calculate offsets. What you did is used when you're declaring, for example, a private type in a C++ class, and don't want the external users to know how it is built, just to point to it. If you're dereferencing it - you **have to** have a definition included.